# how to display text in middle of a div and display list in middle of adjacent div?

Tags: css, html

I need to divide the screen to 2 halves vertically (adjacent to each other) and I need to display a text in middle (horizontally and vertically) of first half and need to display a list (which will be created dynamically using javascript) in the second half. I created a parent div and 2 child divs. But the content is not getting placed in the middle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>VOD</title>
        <script src='js/index.js'></script>
        <style>
            html, body
            {
                height:100%
            }

            #mid
            {
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%; left: 50%;
                z-index: 2;
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255 ,0.5);
            }

            #mid1
            {
                float:left;
                width:50%;
                height:100vh;
                overflow:hidden;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #mid2
            {
                float:left;
                width:50%;
                height:100vh;
                overflow:hidden;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='mid' style="display:none">
            <div id="mid1">
                <h2>text1</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="mid2">
                <h2>text2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

div 'mid' should be displayed only when user presses a button. So I put display as none and it will be enabled in javascript. And just for testing I put text in second div also. Can any one please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you allowed to use flexbox? That can be done easily with flexbox

Comment: Yes. I am allowed to use flex box. Is it possible for you to post the solution?

Comment: Yeah, give me a few seconds

Comment: check my answer with the corresponding working pen. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox to accomplish this:

```
#mid {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vmin;
  justify-content: stretch;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background: blueviolet;
}

#mid-one, #mid-two {
  flex: 1;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#mid-one {
  background: red;
}

#mid-two {
  background: blue;
}
```

Working pen: https://codepen.io/manAbl/pen/WJqRKR?editors=0100 ;

Hope helps :)

Comment: This is the answer to your question

Comment: @ATomCalledStu respect bro

Comment: @kadina it's ok to say thanks I don't mind but here on SO that's unnecessary. Avoid doing that or you will get flags

Comment: @ManuelBlanco: Will this be effected by adding Video element in the body?

Comment: @kadina like 20% bottom and on top on the div's?

Comment: @ManuelBlanco: I will add new question and update the link here in few minutes.

Comment: @ManuelBlanco: I added new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532641/flex-property-is-not-working-as-expected-when-video-element-is-included