# flex property is not working as expected when video element is included

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I need to display video and when user presses menu, I need to divide the screen to 2 halves vertically (adjacent to each other) and I need to display a text in middle (horizontally and vertically) of first half and need to display a list (which will be created dynamically using javascript) in the second half (all this should happen while video is being played in the background. Basically menu should be transparent). I created a parent div and 2 child divs with flex as below.

**html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>VOD</title>
        <script src='js/index.js'>
        </script>
        <style>
            html, body
            {
                height:100%
            }

            #vid
            {
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%; left: 50%;
                z-index: 1;
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            #mid {
                display: flex;
                height: 100vmin;
                justify-content: stretch;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
                background: blueviolet;
                z-index: 2;
            }

            #mid1, #mid2 {
                flex: 1;
            }

            #mid1 {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                background: red;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #mid2 {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                background: blue;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--<video id='vid' src='textMotion.mp4' autoplay loop></video>-->
        <div id='mid' style="display:none">
        <!--<div id='mid'>-->
            <div id='mid1'>
                <h2>text1</h2>
            </div>
            <div id='mid2'>
                <h2>text2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
function changeChannel(e) {
    console.log('received keyEvent : ' + e.keyCode);
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;

    if(keyCode == 77) {
        document.getElementById('mid').style.display = 'block';
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', changeChannel);
```

I am facing below problems.

1) If I press 'M', menu is not getting displayed. It should display transparent screen (with strings in 2 divs) while video running in background.

2) For testing purposes, I commented video element. Then if I press 'M', 2 divs are getting displayed horizontally at the top.

Only if I don't add the attribute "display=none" to mid, it is working as expected. Can any one please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: So you're making a `display: flex` element (the `#mid` element) initially `style="display:none"` but wondering why it's not back at `display: flex` when you use JS `.display = "block"` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I got it. Thanks for pointing that. But is there anyway that I can add both or is there anyway to fix the problem?

Comment: well, simply use `.display = "flex"` :) or see my answer for a nicer solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `#mid` back to `display:block` instead to the desired `display: flex`... Instead:

- create a CSS class `.hidden {display: none;}` and assign it to your `#mid` element
- in JS use `Element.classList` and it's `.toggle()` method to toggle that `'hidden'` class
- Set `#vid` to `z-inedx: -1` since it should be in the *background* while your *#mid* has no `position` set.

```js
var EL_mid = document.getElementById('mid')

function changeChannel(e) {
  if (e.key === 'm') {
    EL_mid.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', changeChannel);
```

```css
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

#vid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#mid {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vmin;
  justify-content: stretch;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background: blueviolet;
  z-index: 2;
}
#mid.hidden {
  display: none; 
}

#mid1,
#mid2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
#mid1 {background: red;}
#mid2 {background: blue;}
```

```html
<video id='vid' src='http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4' autoplay loop></video>

<div id='mid' class="hidden">
  <div id='mid1'>
    <h2>text1</h2>
  </div>
  <div id='mid2'>
    <h2>text2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood now. But one small question. Why video element's z-index negative value? Why it is working if I put video's z-index to negative value? I guessed it should work even though I set as 1 because menu's z-index is 2. But it is not working.

Comment: @kadina `z-index` in order to work should be applied to *positioned* elements by the `position` property and a value other than `static`. Your `#mid` has no `position` set.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here it is, if you're using jquery you can just toggle between `display: hidden` and  `display: block` or you can add a class .hidden that just have this rule: `display: hidden` and toggle onclick if the element has it or not as @RokoCBuljan said.

```
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#vid {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 12%; left: 30%;
  background: slateblue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 360px;
}

#mid {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vmin;
  justify-content: stretch;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background: blueviolet;
}

#mid1, #mid2 {
  flex: 1;
}

#mid1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#mid2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

With the propertie `position: fixed;` I'm getting the div outside of the normal flow and the `z-index` is just to be sure that it will be placed on top of the other divs... If you want to add a nicer appearance add the property (with the toggle function you have to create) of `opacity: 1;` and `opacity: 0;` so it will fade in and fade out

working pen: https://codepen.io/manAbl/pen/WJqRKR?editors=0100 ;

Hope helps :)

Comment: @kadina improved answer